# Why does mount happen over an existing directory?

Tags: mount

An existing directory is needed as a *mount point*.

```
$ ls
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb2 ./datadisk
mount: mount point ./datadisk does not exist
$ mkdir datadisk
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb2 ./datadisk
$
```

I find it confusing since it overlays existing contents of the directory. There are two possible contents of the mount point directory which may get switched unexpectedly (for a user who is not performing the mount).

Why doesn’t `mount` happen into a newly created directory? This is the way how graphical operating systems display removable media. It would be clear if the directory is mounted (exists) or not mounted (does not exist). I am pretty sure there is a good reason but I haven’t been able to discover it yet.

Comment: If you want that behaviour, use `udisksctl`. Why use `mount`?

Comment: Because it is the way of Unix. Because this way it is more flexible, and you can mount then anywhere. Because mounting them anywhere allows you to extend your servers as you need, for instance, getting a new disk for the database partition, moving the data in the DB partition to the new disk, and mount it in the right place to allow the DB data to grow more.

Comment: As a historical note, before Windows and LInux essentially crushed all other OSes, there was a company called Apollo. They wrote a unix-alike (better design than Unix!) operating system. It created the directories on which NFS exports got mounted automatically. In fact, you couldn't mount on a pre-existing directory. HP bought Apollo, threw away the operating system, and used Apollo's 64-bit CPU as HP-PA. Apollo's system of remote procedure calls became OSF's DCE, which apparently lives on inside of Windows. Knowing is half the battle!

Comment: somehow this happens on my ubuntu 14.04,3 system.  i have not investigated, yet.  when my SD card gets mounted, it ends up at a path which has nothing underneath.  if i umount it and try to manually mount it back, the error i get is there is no directory at the mount point.

Comment: @BruceEdiger `better design than Unix!` [citation needed]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is a case of an implementation detail that has leaked.

In a UNIX system, every directory consists of a list of names mapped to *inode* numbers. An inode holds metadata which tells the system whether it is a file, directory, special device, named pipe, etc. If it is a file or directory it also tells the system where to find the file or directory contents on disk. Most inodes are files or directories. The `-i` option to `ls` will list inode numbers.

Mounting a filesystem takes a directory inode and sets a flag on the kernel's in-memory copy to say "actually, when looking for the contents of this directory look at this other filesystem instead" (see slide 10 of [this presentation](http://www.cs.uwyo.edu/~nfrazie1/4740/Chap10.ppt)). This is relatively easy as it's changing a single data item.

Why doesn't it create a directory entry for you pointing at the new inode instead? There are two ways you could implement that, both of which have disadvantages. One is to physically write a new directory into the filesystem - but that fails if the filesystem is readonly! The other is to add to every directory listing process a list of "extra" things that aren't really there. This is fiddly and potentially incurs a small performance hit on every file operation.

If you want dynamically-created mount points, the `automount` system can do this. Special non-disk filesystems can also create directories at will, e.g. `proc`, `sys`, `devfs` and so on.

Edit: see also the answer to [What happens when you 'mount over' an existing folder with contents?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198542/what-happens-when-you-mount-over-an-existing-folder-with-contents?rq=1)

Comment: Except it doesn't set a flag on the inode. `sudo mount --bind / /mnt ; ls /mnt/proc` -> empty. I wonder how it does work.

Comment: The exact operation is in `fs/namespace.c`, I think; I'm not familiar with the source and didn't want to spend too long on drilling to the detail. The "flag on the inode" I got from the linked presentation.

Comment: @sourcejedi: bind mounts only bind the filesystem you actually refer to.  They don't recursively bind other filesystems mounted under it.  This is a handy way to find junk hidden by mounts.  (e.g. if some stuff ended up on the root FS in `/var/cache` some time when `/var` failed to mount.)  See also [`path_resolution(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html).  (Older linux-manpages had that man page in section 2, like die.net)  IDK how Linux actually works internally, to optimize checking every directory component as a possible mount. Maybe pin that VFS entry in cache?

Comment: Right, that's my point...  So `fs/namei.c` (path -> inode lookup) calls into namespace.c though `lookup_mnt()`.  There is a flag on the dentry (directory cache entry).  But that's just an optimization a.k.a. implementation detail.  It doesn't tell you *which* filesystem is mounted there; you have to look in the mount table.  (See m_hash(), for more implementation details.  Linux, at least, avoids additional string comparisons, and AFAICS at the same time manages to re-use dentry's across e.g. bind mounts, because it's written by wizards).

Comment: @PeterCordes: `man 8 mount`:  *`mount --bind foo foo`. The bind `mount` call attaches only (part of)  a  single  filesystem,
 not  possible  submounts. **The entire file hierarchy including sub‐mounts is attached a second place by using**: `mount --rbind olddir newdir`*

Comment: @pjc50 What is "the `automount` system"?

Comment: @Melab https://linux.die.net/man/8/automount ; useful in conjunction with NFS

Answer (score 20):

If `mount(2)` *required* the creation of a new directory to be the mount point, you couldn't mount anything under a read-only filesystem.  That would be dumb, so we can rule that out.

If mount *optionally* created a new directory to be the mountpoint, that would be weird.  It's not like mount/unmount happen all the time, so putting extra logic in the kernel to do these two steps with a single system call would not be an important speedup.  Just leave it up to user-space to make a `mkdir(2)` system call if it wants one.  Dmitry's answer points out that having `mount(2)` do both things would make it non-atomic.  And you'd want an extra argument to `mount(2)` with mode flags like `open(2)` takes, for `O_CREAT`, `O_EXCL`, etc.  It would just be silly compared to letting user-space do it.

Or maybe you were asking about having `mount(8)` (the traditional program that makes `mount(2)` system calls) do this?  That would be possible, but there's already a perfectly good `mkdir(1)` for the job, and Unix's design is all about good small tools that can be combined.  If you want a tool that does both, it's easy to write a shell script to build that tool out of two simpler tools.  (Or, as muru commented, `udisksctl` already does this, so you don't have to write it.)  Also, Linux's normal `mount(8)` from util-linux supports `mount -o x-mount.mkdir[=mode]` using it's `x-` syntax for options for userspace, rather than options to be passed to the filesystem.

---

#### Now the more interesting question: why does there have to be a directory on the parent filesystem at all?

Like pjc50's answer points out (no relation, even though he has my initials!) , having mount points show up in directory listings would then require an extra check on every `readdir()`.

Having mount points exist as directories in the directory containing them (on the parent FS) is a nice trick.  `readdir()` doesn't have to notice that it is a mount point at all.  That only happens **if** the mount point is used as a path component.  Path resolution of course does have to check the mount table for every directory component of a path.

Comment: `If mount(2) required the creation of a new directory to be the mount point, you couldn't mount anything under a read-only filesystem. That would be dumb` - I'd argue it smarter:  From the user's perspective, a read-only filesystem shouldn't change, but allowing mounts means it can

Comment: @Izkata: Making a filesystem read-only doesn't mean that whole subtree of the VFS is frozen.  It could have symlinks pointing to read-write directories, or already have read-write mount points under it when the parent fs was remounted `ro`.  There are many use cases for read-only filesystems where your argument doesn't make sense.

Comment: `man 8 mount`: *`x-mount.mkdir[=mode]`  Allow  to make a target directory (mountpoint).  The optional argument mode specifies the filesystem access mode used for `mkdir(2)` in octal  notation.   The default mode is 0755.  This functionality is supported only for root users.*

Comment: I don't see any important use cases of read-only filesystems with mounted read-write filesystems, especially not in the early Unix. @PeterCordes

Comment: @kubanczyk: read-only root filesystem, with a read-write `/tmp` and `/home`.  Or read-only NFS-mounted `/usr` with a local `/usr/local` mounted on it.  Or more generally, any shared read-only image with a modifiable part mounted over it.  (local mods to a read-only image can also be done on a per-file basis with custom filesystems like [overlayfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Overlay_filesystem) or other union filesystems for Linux, used on LiveCD bootable images.)  I was initially thinking of the root FS initially mounted RO at boot, but making it rw can happen before other mounts.

Comment: Yes, as I said: no important use cases (of read-only filesystems with mounted read-write filesystems). So it seems like a case of premature optimization in early Unix.

Comment: @kubanczyk: huh? I don't see how anything about this could be seen as an "optimization".  My claim is the opposite: having `mount(2)` optionally or unconditionally do a `mkdir(2)` that actually made it to disk on the parent FS would be premature optimization.  (Or even pessimization, since you'd have to remove and recreate the dir every time you wanted to mount the same fs in the same place.)  The only sane way for it to work anything like this would be to just virtually create a new directory, which wouldn't appear in the parent after unmount (and wouldn't preclude mounting on a rofs).

Comment: @PeterCordes I think you misunderstood what I meant.  Not the contents of another filesystem changing, but the appears-to-be readonly filesystem changing when something gets mounted.  To use your other examples, it's akin to the symlink being created, not the symlink existing.

Comment: @Izkata:  No, I did know what you meant.  I was arguing that such a change to Unix semantics would not be good or sensible, because that's not what it means for a FS to be read-only.  I can see the argument that it might be interesting for it to mean what you're suggesting, but that's a significant separate change to Unix semantics that could be implemented separately from having `mount(2)` require an `mkdir(2)`.  Linux (and I assume other modern Unices) give even more flexibility to the admin with stuff like `mount --bind` to graft subtrees of a mount on to other places in the VFS.

Answer (score 12):

Mounting to existing directory makes a call to `mount` practically atomic: it either succeeds or fails, at least from user's perspective. If `mount` had to create the mountpoint itself, it would have two points of failure, making it impossible to guarantee a clean roll back. Imagine the following scenario:

1. `mount` successfully creates the mountpoint
2. `mount` tries to mount a new file system to that directory, but fails
3. `mount` tries to remove the mountpoint, but fails

The system ends up with a side effect of a failed `mount`.

Here's another one:

1. `umount` successfully unmounts a file system
2. `umount` tries to remove the mountpoint, but fails

Now, should `umount` return success or failure?

Comment: `mount` has 8 different return codes for errors which can also be combined. It could just add another one when the directory remove fails. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html#RETURN_CODES

Comment: I think the OP is asking why the mountpoint needs to be an existing directory at all, not why doesn't the `mount` system call create it.  Although maybe that was just my interpretation / expectation of what I thought the OP meant to ask, or what I would have asked if I was asking.

Answer (score 3):

Another case that can occur:

When you boot, a basic read only image is load on root directory. So you would like to override it when you would like to mound real root. So you can imagine that mount syscall just swap the `ro` mountpoint to `rw`.

Here, lets imagine you have a filesystem issue on root mountpoint, you would like to be able to try to repair it. With mount overlap, you can unmount filesystem and use `fsck` provided into basic image to solve it.

This feature can also be useful in systems that need strong security to be make track of change between a `ro` partition and a `rw` one.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question.  Are you pointing out that if `mount` *required* creating a new directory at the location of the mountpoint that you couldn't mount anything on top of a read-only filesystem?  The opening paragraph is confusing: that's not how Linux initrd works.  It uses the `pivot_root` system call to change the root fs, not just mount more stuff over it.  That made it hard to follow your logic in the next paragraphs, because I thought you were talking about `pivot_root(2)`.

Comment: @PeterCordes - [linux hasn't used an initrd for many years](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt): *When switching another root device, initrd would `pivot_root` and then `umount` the ramdisk. But **initramfs is rootfs: you can neither `pivot_root` rootfs, nor unmount it**. Instead delete everything out of rootfs to free up the space (`find -xdev / -exec rm {} \;`), overmount rootfs with the new root (`cd /newmount; mount --move . /; chroot .`), attach stdin/stdout/stderr to the new /dev/console, and `exec` the new `init`*

Comment: @mikeserv: Neat!  I hadn't realized that the basic mechanism for switching roots changed when we started using initramfs instead of initrd.  From a "make sure the right kernel modules end up in it" admin perspective, they're identical >.<.  **I still think this doesn't really answer the question very well**.  It seems to assume the "mount under a rofs is impossible" interpretation, and gives a very specific problem case (which seems unlikely because initramfs isn't mounted read-only at boot.  And even if it is, it can simply be remounted read-write without affecting the cpio.gz image.)

Comment: @PeterCordes - i dont really understand this answer. i just saw your comment - the initramfs is a file system - it cant really ever be read-only - its fs cache incarnate.

Answer (score 2):

I've always wondered that too.

A simple wrapper such as:

```
#!/bin/sh
eval "mkdir -p \"\$$#\"" 
/bin/mount "$@"
```

saved as an executable script named `mount` in a directory overriding `/bin` in your PATH should take care of this if it bothers you too much

(Before running the actual `mount` binary, it creates a directory named after the last argument to `mount`, if such directory doesn't exist already.)

---

Alternatively, if you don't want failed invocations of the `mount` wrapper to create directories, you can do:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
eval "lastArg=\"\$$#\""
test -d "$lastArg" || { mkdir "$lastArg"; madeDir=1; }
/bin/mount "$@"  ||  {  test -z "$madeDir" || rmdir "$lastArg"; }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `mount` command then use the directory thus created?

Comment: @muru That's what the last line does.

Comment: Oh, so you mean it should be used thus: `mount /dev/foo /some/path`? I assumed it would work like `udisksctl` does, so you would run `mount /dev/foo`.

Comment: You can get the last cmdline arg without `eval` to expand `$#`, using `"${@:-1}"`.  I tested this with DASH, since I think it doesn't support anything beyond what POSIX sh is required to support.   `/bin/dash -c 'echo ${@:-1}' foo bar` prints `bar`.

Comment: you can use `man -o x-mount.mkdir`...