# Mounting only a particular path of a filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, linux-kernel

After a while, I finally came to understand how bind mounts are indistinguishable from "regular" mounts in Linux (other than by being mounted with `--bind`). If `/dev/sda1` is mounted on `/mnt` and `/mnt/variable_data` is then bind mounted on `/var`, the only difference between the two is that the root of the filesystem on `/dev/sda1` is mounted at `/mnt` while the path `/variable_data` on that same filesystem is mounted at `/var` (in the virtual/root filesystem).

My question is two fold:

1. Assuming that I have not run `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` (meaning that there is no `/mnt/variable_data`), how can I mount the `/variable_data` inside `sda1` at `/var`?
2. How can the above be accomplished with `fstab`?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest, and possibly only way, is to mount `/dev/sda1` first. You can mount the device read only if you are concerned about accidental changes, but [bind mount permissions can be tricky](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128336/why-doesnt-mount-respect-the-read-only-option-for-bind-mounts) to get set. It is also possibly to [*over mount*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198542/what-happens-when-you-mount-over-an-existing-folder-with-contents) the directory on top of the device. In other words, in general, you can mount `/dev/sda1` to `/var` and then mount `/var/variable_data` to `/var`.

A potential issue with this is that the mounting process is not atomic and there is a chance something could get written to `/var` in the brief moment that `/dev/sda1` is mounted there. Even if `/dev/sda1` is mounted read only, this could cause problems depending on how write failures are handled. As `/var` is often a separate partition mounted in fstab, this should not be a problem.

Comment: Could there be some stackable filesystem or something of the sort that achieves this. Like, you'd specify `/dev/sda1` as the source, `subtreefs` as the type, and the subtree's path as an option?

Comment: @Melab I am not aware of a technical limitation why there couldn't be a *stackable* filesystem, but I am not sure what benefits it provides over a bind mount.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the man page of [`mount(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html), I don't think you can do that directly. The system call doesn't take a path that would be used to consider a subtree of the mounted filesystem. There's just the source device, target path, filesystem type, mount flags (the common options like `ro` and `nosuid`), and an opaque `data` field that is interpreted by the filesystem itself (the filesystem-specific options).

It seems you need to mount the device to a temporary path, then bindmount the subtree you want, and finally unmount the first filesystem. Apart from the unmounting, you might able to do that from fstab. Something like this worked on Ubuntu (with systemd):

```
# fstab
/dev/somedevice      /tmpmnt      ext4      auto,rw
/tmpmnt/var          /var         none      auto,bind
```

Comment: The subtree would most likely be part of the options.

Comment: @Melab, mm, I suppose the path would have to go to the VFS layer, and the options field that takes a free-form/string argument is interpreted by the filesystem code. There's a mention in the man page of the `mount(8)` utility, that e.g. NFS and others want a binary argument, so it doesn't seem even possible to piggyback anything on the FS-specific options. (And there's no mention of the possibility in the manual, anyway.)