# Unexpected results when mounting two drives on a single mount point

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, partition

I was running out of `/tmp` space on one of my servers today so I attached a new 100GB disk to the system and did the following without unmounting `/usr/tmpDSK` from `/tmp`:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvde
mount /dev/xvde /tmp
```

and now `df -h` outputs as:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/usr/tmpDSK      98G  4.5G   89G   5% /tmp
/dev/xvde        98G  4.5G   89G   5% /tmp
```

The size of `/usr/tmpDSK` shows :

```
[root@server2 usr]# ll -h /usr/tmpDSK
-rw------- 1 root root 2.3G Jan 27 17:32 /usr/tmpDSK
```

Different forums suggested using `mhddfs` to mount multiple drives on a single mount point, but I just did it directly and it seems to have worked -- or am I missing something?

I am hoping to better understand what actually happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you mount a filesystem on top of a directory, the contents of that directory is hidden until the filesystem is unmounted.

If the directory was previously a mount point for another filesystem or not does not matter. If it was, then you need to unmount the new filesystem to access the files on the old filesystem (or to unmount the old filesystem).

Related:

- [Mounting multiple devices at a single mount point on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/mounting-multiple-devices-at-a-single-mount-point-on-linux)
- [Access to original contents of mount point](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/access-to-original-contents-of-mount-point)

---

I can't say much about the `df` output.  On my OpenBSD system, the two filesystems will have correct individual stats in the `df` output.