# How to make multiple NFS host directories appear as one on NFS client?

Tags: directory, lvm, nfs, unionfs

I have 6 Ubuntu VM's on one network. Five of them has 2 TB disks attached. I have created NFS directories for those disks and share them on the last VM that acts as a client and a server. How I can make those disks appear as one on a VM. For now I see 5 directories. I have looked at mergefs and unionfs but I don't think I understand how it should be done properly.
[image: NFS client sees NFS hosts]

My goal is to have a 10 TB directory for files on my application that will be published on that last VM which sees nfs directories.

Comment: It is probably be possible somehow, but I doubt this will be useful and reliable. Why not move all disks to one system and create a RAID?

Comment: The host of servers does not allow more than 2 TB per VM. So I got 5 VMs with 2 TB each...

Comment: Have you looked into these similar questions https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/mounting-multiple-devices-at-a-single-mount-point-on-linux, https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/32091/software-raid-alternative-with-file-level-striping-not-block-striping, or https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way by using mhddfs which helped me creating one mounted directory from NFS directories.
[image]

Comment: would you care to explain configuration used  (i.e. line in /etc/fstab) ? and also do not post text as image.